# Java: Which CLASS does the object returned by list.listIterator() belong to?

Tags: java, list, class, iteration, iterable

A question about iteration in Java. I'm (somewhat) familiar with the interfaces Iterator, ListIterator and Iterable, i.e. I get the idea behind them. But this is also what my question is about.

If I have an instance of ArrayList, let's simply call this instance 'list', and if I then make the method call 'list.listIterator()', then which CLASS does the resulting (i.e. returned) object belong to?

I do understand that it must be a class that implements the interface ListIterator, but that still doesn't tell me WHICH actual specific CLASS it belongs to. And the online documentation does not seem to tell me this either. Or is it simply an 'internal' - and therefore anonymous/unnamed - Java class?

Thanks!
Holland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out by doing

```
System.out.println(new ArrayList<String>().listIterator().getClass());
```

You'll see that the class is declared inside `ArrayList` and is called `ListItr`.

It is `private`. There are good reasons for doing it this way. Firstly, it enables the writers of `ArrayList` to change the implementation without breaking anybody's code. Also, you don't need to care what the actual class is; all that matters is that it obeys the contract for `ListIterator`.

Comment: Well, I'd think that answers the question (and also taught/reminded me of something, i.e. the use of getClass). Many thanks!

Comment: Will accept the answer as soon as possible (there's a waiting time for that).

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Online documentation tells you what you can expect from the API and what you can do, you can look into source code to find the details you want, so here you go:

**From Java source code:**

```
public ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: "+index);
    return new ListItr(index);
}
```

Above tells that you will get a implementation of `ListItr` and below is the actual implementation of class:

```
 private class ListItr extends Itr implements ListIterator<E> {
    ListItr(int index) {
        super();
        cursor = index;
    }

    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return cursor != 0;
    }

    public int nextIndex() {
        return cursor;
    }

    public int previousIndex() {
        return cursor - 1;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E previous() {
        checkForComodification();
        int i = cursor - 1;
        if (i < 0)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
        if (i >= elementData.length)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        cursor = i;
        return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
    }

    public void set(E e) {
        if (lastRet < 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        checkForComodification();

        try {
            ArrayList.this.set(lastRet, e);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
    }

    public void add(E e) {
        checkForComodification();

        try {
            int i = cursor;
            ArrayList.this.add(i, e);
            cursor = i + 1;
            lastRet = -1;
            expectedModCount = modCount;
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
    }
}
```